# bad array subscript error in associative array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary program in Bash with the following options : 1. Add a word
2. Update meaning
3. Print dictionary
4. Search a word
5. Search by keyword

For the same, I am creating 2 associative arrays, 1 to store the word - meaning and other to store words-keyword.

The problem is I am not able to store values in the array. Everytime I try to do it, it gives me an error 
dict[$word]: bad array subscript

Here is the code for part 1

```
echo
echo -n "Enter a word : "
read $word
echo
echo -n "Enter it's meaning : "
read $meaning
echo
echo -n "Enter some keywords(with space in between) to describe the word : "
read $keyword

dict[$word]=$meaning
keywords[$word]=$keyword
;;
```

I also tried inserting the following code to remove new line as suggested in some posts but ended up with same result.

```
word=`echo $word | grep -s '\n'`
keyword=`echo $keyword | grep -s '\n'`
```

Have also tried the following way :

```
dict["$word"]="$meaning"
keywords["$word"]="$keyword"
;;
```

Output : 
**dict[$word]: bad array subscript**

Answer (score 4):

When reading a variable you preface the variable name with a `$` (or wrap in `$(` and `)`).

When assigning a value to a variable you do **not** preface the variable name with a `$`.

In your example your 3x `echo/read` sessions are attempting to **assign** values to your variables, but you've prefaced your variables with `$`, which means your variables are not getting set as you expect; this in turn could be generating your error because `$word` is not set/defined (depends on version of bash).

You should be able to see what I mean with the following code snippet:

```
unset word
echo
echo -n "Enter a word : "
read $word
echo ".${word}."
```

What do you get as ouput?  `..` ? `.<whatever_you_typed_in>.` ?

You may also have a problem with your associative arrays (depending on bash version); as George has mentioned, you should play it safe and explicitly declare your associative arrays.

I would suggest editing your input script like such (remove leading `$` on your `read` variables; explicitly declaring your associative arrays):

```
echo
echo -n "Enter a word : "
read word
echo
echo -n "Enter it's meaning : "
read meaning
echo
echo -n "Enter some keywords(with space in between) to describe the word : "
read keyword

# print some debug messages:
echo "word=.${word}."
echo "meaning=.${meaning}."
echo "keyword=.${keyword}."

# declare arrays as associative
declare -A dict keywords

# assign values to arrays
dict[$word]=$meaning
keywords[$word]=$keyword

# verify array indexes and values
echo "dict index(es)    : ${!dict[@]}"
echo "dict value(s)     : ${dict[@]}"
echo "keywords index(es): ${!keywords[@]}"
echo "keywords value(s) : ${keywords[@]}"
```

Comment: I admit that i failed to notice the `$` in the read commands! My bad!

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou - to be honest, I missed it the first time around, too ... couldn't figure out why my cut-n-paste of the OP's `echo/read` statements were leading to empty variables !?!?! :-)

Comment: I totally failed to notice that and had spent considerable time on the problem

Answer (score 3):

In my bash 4.4 , this is not raising any error but is not working correctly either:

```
$ w="one";m="two";d["$w"]="$m";declare -p d
declare -a d=([0]="two")
```

It is obvious that bash determines array d as a normal array and not as an associative array.

On the contrary, this one works fine:

```
$ w="one";m="two";declare -A d;d["$w"]="$m";declare -p d
declare -A d=([one]="two" )
```

According to bash manual, you need first to `declare -A` an array in order to be used as an associative one.